# PHP: Storing Strings via Array

Tags: php

I have a question about this situation, How could I store string via Array?
this is my code

```
<?php
$octets = array($_POST["oct1"],$_POST["oct2"],$_POST["oct3"],$_POST["oct4"]);
$octlenfnl = count($octets) - 1;
$binoctstr = 0 ;
if($_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255)
{
    for($i=0;$i<=$octlenfnl;$i++){
        echo str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , "&nbsp";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid IP!";
}

?>
```

It outputs entered IP to Binary octets just like this `11111111 0001000 10010101 10010101`, they have spaces between the Octets, how can I split them and store it to array that is accessible globally?

Thanks

Comment: Or build the array to start with rather than a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isntead of echoing out your results store them into an array something like this

```
<?php
$octets = array($_POST["oct1"],$_POST["oct2"],$_POST["oct3"],$_POST["oct4"]);
$octlenfnl = count($octets) - 1;
$binoctstr = 0 ;
$binaryarray = array();
if($_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255)
{
  for($i=0;$i<=$octlenfnl;$i++){
      $binaryarray[] = str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }
}
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid IP!";
    }

//to echo out your results you can do this as a comma separated string
echo implode(",",$binaryarray);
//or if you wish to access a specific segment you can do this where $key is the array element you want
echo $binaryarray[$key];  

?>
```

UPDATE EDIT FOR SIMPLIFIED CODE

You can potentially simplfy the code a little I think like this save you creating a second array and just manipulating your existing array. Unless you need that initial array for anything this should work fine

```
<?php
$octets = array($_POST["oct1"],$_POST["oct2"],$_POST["oct3"],$_POST["oct4"]);
$binoctstr = 0 ;
if($_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255 && $_POST["oct1"] <= 255)
{
  for($i=0;$i<=count($octets);$i++){
      $octets [$i] = str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }
}
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid IP!";
    }

//to echo out your results you can do this as a comma separated string
echo implode(",",$octets );
//or if you wish to access a specific segment you can do this where $key is the array element you want
echo $octets[$key];  

?>
```

Comment: @user1999909 I've updated the code example with a slightly simplified version

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$arr=explode(' ', "11111111 0001000 10010101 10010101");`

Comment: just like this?
`$arr=explode(' ', str_pad(decbin($octets[$i]), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`
inside the "for"?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$resultAsArray = explode(" ", $binaryOctets);
```